# Unable to update because of bind issue on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, updates, bind

How can I completly uninstall Bind 9 on Ubuntu. Its causing issues with keeping the server up to date as shown.

```
  **root@cp11:~# apt-get upgrade**

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     bind9 : Depends: libbind9-80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed
             Depends: libdns81 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed
             Depends: libisc83 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed
             Depends: libisccc80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed
             Depends: libisccfg82 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed
             Depends: liblwres80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed
             Depends: bind9utils (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2) but 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5 is installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.    
    root@cp11:~# apt-get -f install
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree  
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      bind9
    Suggested packages:
      bind9-doc
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      bind9
    1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 196 not upgraded.
    1 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/343 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of bind9:
     bind9 depends on libbind9-80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2); however:
      Version of libbind9-80 on system is 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5.
     bind9 depends on libdns81 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2); however:
      Version of libdns81 on system is 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5.
     bind9 depends on libisc83 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2); however:
      Version of libisc83 on system is 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5.
     bind9 depends on libisccc80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2); however:
      Version of libisccc80 on system is 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5.
     bind9 depends on libisccfg82 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2); however:
      Version of libisccfg82 on system is 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5.
     bind9 depends on liblwres80 (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2); however:
      Version of liblwres80 on system is 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5.
     bind9 depends on bind9utils (= 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.2); however:
      Version of bind9utils on system is 1:9.8.1.dfsg.P1-4ubuntu0.5.
    dpkg: error processing bind9 (--configure):
     dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
   No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
     bind9
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an apparently radical way of possibly sorting out this error.

I saw this on Ubuntu Forums and a reference to:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Pa...otingProcedure

I tried this on my system (server11) and it did not work but I'm putting the solution here anyway. On my system I could already see at `apt-get clean` it already gave the same error as before.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Original reference:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2068352&page=2

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my english, i´m brazilian... but in my case (ubuntu 12.04 LTS) I resolve with

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/available /var/lib/dpkg/available-bad
sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get -f autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get -f autoremove (again)
```